# Error while trying to scaffolding identity pages in a Blazor WASM app

Tags: identity, blazor-webassembly

When scaffolding adding new identity pages (right click on project > Add > New Scaffold Item > Identity) I get an error after I select the pages and click the add button:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: package restore
> failed. Rolling Back Package Changes...

I have 3 projects in the solution: client, server and shared. I am trying to scaffold in the server project.

I have cleared nuget cache and rebuilt the solution but that did not work. I have also deleted the bin and obj files and restarted VS.

**This is easily reproducible by creating a new Blazor WASM solution, select .NET 5, ASP.NET hosted, individual accounts. Right click on the server project > Add > New Scaffold Item > Identity > select pages > click Add.**

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have used the same scaffold in my project without problem.  Also, just followed the reproducible steps and all was fine.  Maybe an update to Visual Studio required?

Comment: Thanks Neil, that is good to know. Unfortunately it looks like I will have to do a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have installed the NuGet package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design.

The thing is that **every time that you scaffold an item it updates Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** NuGets to the latest version, so **you need to update all related to Entity Framework packages** as well (to be compatible).

Also a **Data folder with ApplicationDbContext.cs is created** inside your Identity folder:

[image]

and if you already have this ApplicationDbContext class on another place in your solution, there will be a collision.

For me that was the problem: **I had this file on two places** - in ProjectName.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationDbContext.cs and in ProjectName.Data.ApplicationDbContext.cs and I couldn't scaffold another item, it worked just for the first one.

So when the ProjectName.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationDbContext.cs was deleted, the scaffolding worked again as usual.